# Hibernate Session.SaveOrUpdate method is calling select before every item - is there a way to batch these selects?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, batch-processing

I am using java/hibernate/mysql. I am creating a list of objects which i want to save to the database. Some of the items are new and some of them are already in the database (I do not know which ones). For this reason I am using session.SaveOrUpdate method and it works fine inserting when necessary and updating when necessary.

The problem is every time i call saveOrUpdate(myObject) I see there is a select call to check if this record already exsists, so if I loop over N objects I  have N - select queries. Is there any way I can batch these selects together?

Does this behavior have a significant affect on performance?

Thanks

the log I am getting is :

```
Hibernate: select price0_.product_id as product1_3_0_, price0_.store_id as 
store2_3_0_, price0_.date_updated as date3_3_0_, price0_.price as price3_0_, 
price0_.quality as quality3_0_, price0_.update_source as update6_3_0_ 
from realworld.price price0_ where price0_.product_id=? and price0_.store_id=?

Hibernate: select price0_.product_id as product1_3_0_, price0_.store_id as 
store2_3_0_, price0_.date_updated as date3_3_0_, price0_.price as price3_0_, 
price0_.quality as quality3_0_, price0_.update_source as update6_3_0_ 
from realworld.price price0_ where price0_.product_id=? and price0_.store_id=?

Hibernate: insert into realworld.price 
(date_updated, price, quality, update_source, product_id, store_id) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  

Hibernate: insert into realworld.price 
(date_updated, price, quality, update_source, product_id, store_id) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The code generating this is:

```
for (Price price : prices){
        HibernateCurrentSession.currentSession().merge(price); 
        i++;
        if ( i % batchsize == 0 ) { 
            //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
            HibernateCurrentSession.currentSession().flush();
            HibernateCurrentSession.currentSession().clear();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, those selects and what not are all executed in the same transaction so they should work pretty fast. The reason why you get them could be the fact that for an existing entry Hibernate might want to first check the version field (by comparing it's current value to the one already in the db) and this would issue a select before the update. More details on the behaviour of saveOrUpdate can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-saveorupdate)

I don't think there's a way for you to controll or batch those selects in this context. What you can do to have a more efficient operation is something like this:

- you have a List of entity instances, you want to persist their current state to the db, and you don't know/care which ones already have state persisted to the db and which are new
- in a given transaction, you re-attach all those instances to the current Hibernate session using `Session.merge(obj)`
- now you can simply make the necessary modifications to each of these instances (I.E. as per your business logic needs). You no longer need to call any persist/update methods on them to have the modifs persisted to the db, this will happen automatically when the transaction is commited.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using merge but I am still seeing the same behavior. Regarding the version field I did not define a version column - as I understand it I Hibernate should be using pessimistic locking in this case - is that correct? Is it possible to perform saveOrUpdate without having a select query first?

Comment: Could you post a bunch of those logs that shows the selects, and also mention what's the code that generates them? Honestlly I've had similar issues with hibernate, where it does a bunch of SQL (especially selects) without any apparent reason. And, as always, don't forget that you can do your own native queries in SQL via Hibernate if you want to, and automatically marshall the results to corresponding beans

Comment: for (Price price : prices){
              HibernateCurrentSession.currentSession().merge(price); 
   i++;
   if ( i % batchsize == 0 ) { 
    //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
    HibernateCurrentSession.currentSession().flush();
    HibernateCurrentSession.currentSession().clear();
   }

Comment: Well, what you're doing there is not too good. Hibernate takes care of batching your queries all by itself, as long as those queries are in the same transaction. By force-flushing your session you're asking Hibernate to do a lot more then just commit transactions, this adds unneeded overhead. Just open a transaction, inside it get all your needed entities so that they are attached, modify then as you wish (via setters/getters, etc), then commit the transaction. Hibernate will batch this as needed.

Comment: I am flushing in order to take advantage of the hibernate.jdbc.batch_size property [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts). I tried removing the flushing but i still get the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Can you post our mapping file? This could be because of property '[select-before-update](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class)' to true. By default it is false. If this is indeed false and you are using optimistic locking, select will not happen before update. Check [this](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Versioning-Optimistic-Locking-in-Hibernate.aspx), which explains about optimistic locking in Hibernate and how updates happen.

Comment: Thanks, I am using annotations so i don't have a mapping file. In any case I did not specify select-before-update = true. Like i wrote above as far as I understand I am using pessimistic locking since I haven't added a @version column- Is it possible i am using optimistic locking without knowing about it?

Comment: I don't think Hib. is necessarely using pessimistick locking by default if no version fields are declared. I think it just doesn't do any locking. At any rate, if you have your Hibernate-generated SQL outputted, it's easy to see if he does pessimistick locking because it will be reflected in that SQL, such as doing "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" or "SELECT... FOR SHARE" (depending on the DB you're using). If IN FACT Hibernate does do those selects like this due to pessimistick locking, try disabling it: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking